# Magento 2 cloud: Copy file via ssh (locally)

Tags: magento2, magento2-cloud

Tryed to copy log file locally using `scp`.

```
scp XXXX@ssh.ap-3.magento.cloud:var/log/payment.log /var/www/some-folder/payment.log
```

Result:

```
Could not create directory '/app/.ssh'.
Warning: Permanently added 'ssh.ap-3.magento.cloud,52.65.30.37' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

`magento-cloud repo:cat` command returns only files from git.

**Is there a way to copy a file locally from the cloud using console?**

#### UPD:

At the moment, the problem is not observed.

Comment: Do you run scp command on server or localy?

Comment: @KAndy, yes. From cloud to local.

Answer (score 4):

Use magento-cloud scp tool:

```
magento-cloud scp remote:var/log/fileToCopy .
```

For more information magento-cloud scp --help

Answer (score 0):

Use `rsync` instead of `scp`.
This command copies file from a remote server to local machine:

```
rsync XXXX@ssh.ap-3.magento.cloud:var/log/payment.log /var/www/some-folder/payment.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this below command & it will copy all files under **var/log** into your current directory from where your run this command

```
magento-cloud scp remote:var/log/* .
```

**After Running this commands:**

1. Select the Project
2. Choose Environment to Copy files from.

***Attached screenshot***

[image]